# How to generate custom training model for stanford relation extractor

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am beginner to stanford-corenlp, Can someone help help in training the custom relation extractor, I refered the following site but I am not clear how to generate the custom model first, which is with the .corp extension. 
https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/relationExtractor.html#training

Thanks in Advance.